# Reverse plotting in matlab

Tags: matlab

How to get data points of this image using matlab. I want data points (0,1,0,-1):

[image: How to get data points of this image using matlab. I want data points (0,1,0,-1)]
can any one please help me with this?

Comment: Look for the XData and YData properties of the children of the axes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract data from figure in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934595/how-to-extract-and-filter-data-from-figure-in-matlab)